# How to use XSLT to convert a MathML file to SSML

Tags: xslt, mathml, ssml

I want to convert a MathML to speech. For this, I proposed to use XSLT which can convert an XML file to a text file which I can use to make an SSML file or an HTML file. So how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: That's going to be a very big task, and you are not providing enough detail to see if it would be feasible for your project or not. How many target languages do you have? What type of MathML do you have: Is it notation-oriented or structure-oriented, or does it mix both approaches? You would need a lot of mappings from symbols to words in all of your target languages, and furthermore you would need mappings for certain concepts, which are represented as MathML elements.

Comment: The MathML that would be targeted would be mixed and I am aware that I would be needing lots of mapping and for that, I have gone through various research studies to reduce the verbosity and ambiguity in the speech. But I don't know **How to code** it given I am comfortable with Cpp and Java and have taken introductory course of Data Structures and Algorithms

Comment: If you're not familiar with XSLT yet, I suggest you consider to do it in Cpp or Java. XSLT is a not an OOP language, but follows a functional programming paradigm, which has the important property of not keeping any state and function calls are not having side effects. It may be hard to learn a new programming paradigm, which is not object-oriented, by tackling such a hard problem. Learning XSLT is great and fun, but better start with simpler problems.

Comment: One example for a difficult problem: If you have a large Greek sigma character, it may in some context be spoken as "sigma" and in some context as "sum". To distinguish these cases and figure out the correct pronounciation in the given context, you might have to take quite a few factors into account. In XSLT you would have to model all these contexts as XPath expressions and wrap them into a large switch statement (xsl:choose in XSLT)